# How to get the row count in a excel sheet with Apache POI with Event API

Tags: apache-poi, xls

I am using Apache POI Event API to read large excel worksheets.

The whole operation is lenghy, becouse I have to put all the data to database. 
I would like to display progress of import, ie

```
Processing sheet 1 of 5, row 5123 of 40000.
```

At the begining of file there are all sheets declared, so no problem with sheet count.

Is there a record at the begining of a file or a sheet from which I could read the number of rows in the sheet? If so, which record it is and which property I should check to find out the number of rows?

Or the only way to determine the number of rows is to wait until all row records ar read?

Comment: Before counting number of rows in excel sheet,we need to iterate each row and check whether it is empty or not.We need to read all the rows

Comment: I do not care if the row is empty or not, I would just use the number of last row. Something similar to `RowRec getLastCol()` method. But if it is not possible whitout iterating over all the records, then I will have to skip the total number, and just display the current row number.

Answer (score 1):

There are methods for getting the number of rows in a sheet:

```
getLastRowNum()
```

and

```
getPhysicalNumberOfRows()
```

Comment: What is the basic difference between getLastRowNum() and getPhysicalNumberOfRows()?

Answer (score 0):

`getLastRowNum() return ->0` if sheet has 1 row and if sheet has no rows this function `return-> 0` but `getPhysicalNumberOfRows() return ->0` if  no rows are in the sheet, if sheet has one row it will `return->1`